# Windows Store Apps - Console App IPC named pipe connection

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, ipc, windows-8.1

I need to implement a **IPC** with namedpipes between a **Windows Store App** and a **localservice** (or .net-Console-Application). I know there are [no alternatives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945.aspx) for named pipes in the new Windows Runtime in Windows 8.1, but it was announce that this limitation has been gone after installing **Update 1** on 8.1.

I searched for some examples but was not able to find anything helpful. Within this [MSDN-Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182410.aspx) there is a small reference on what should have been changed/added to the Windows Runtime API.

On local service side there is something like

```
using (NamedPipeClientStream stream = new NamedPipeClientStream("EAPI"))
{
    // do something ...
}
```

but I can not find anything opening a communication on Windows Store App side.

Comment: Can NamedPipes be used in Store apps with Update 1 on 8.1?

Comment: This is the question I hoped to get answered

Comment: Can you provide the source/link where you found `this limitation has been gone after installing Update 1 on 8.1`

Comment: @Raghavendra : [Non MS](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2014/04/02/sideloaded-windows-8-1-apps-can-access-net-and-win32-apis/), [MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn631247.aspx)

Comment: Not sure if namedpipes is allowed, but I am using NetTCP binding to achieve communication between a Store app and a Local service

Comment: @Raghavendra Me too. But I must use the API of an older software, using namedpipes and there is no nettcp interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer to your "I can not find anything opening a communication on Windows Store App side" ...

Please look into 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn640582.aspx

Note: I haven't tried loopback or brokered runtime myself. They have certain limitation and I am not sure they would apply to your scenarios. But those are worth reading.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped to get :P ... But you are right very worth reading and did the trick to help me out of this problem. +50 ;)

Comment: @Martin Good to know. I am working on the same problem. I will update if I find out anything interesting :)